# Shortcut for array-matrix helper plugin in Spyder

Tags: python, numpy, spyder

In the IPython console of the Spyder interface, everytime I try to type a closing curly bracket with `AltGr`+`Shift`+`*`, instead it opens the array-matrix helper plugin of the *numpy* library. But [here](https://bitbucket.org/spyder-ide/spyderlib/pull-requests/98/add-array-matrix-helper-in-editor-and/diff) they say that the shortcut for this feature is `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`*`.
Am I missing something? (probably) Can you help me?

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) This seems like a bug. Please open an issue in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) so we don't forget to address it.

Comment: I went ahead and changed the shortcuts to introduce matrices in Spyder. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder dev here*) To fix this problem we decided to change the shortcuts we had defined to introduce arrays in Spyder 3.0.

Since Spyder 3.0 beta3 these shortcuts will be:

1. `Ctrl+M` for the 2D array helper
2. `Ctrl+Alt+M` for the 1D array helper

*Note*: For reference, this change was done in [this commit](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/commit/d2e395868aa6d4e0efb355e8c67a1b30575b5227)